# Writing a For loop to delete words in a list from a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a listof strings:

```
non_dogs =['tiger_shark', 'upright', 'walking_stick', 'water_bottle']
```

i want to delete the strings in that list from the dataframe, how do i do that using a for loop using a code like this:

```
clean_breeds =clean_images[(clean_images['dog_breed']== 'tiger_shark')].index
clean_images.drop(clean_breeds,inplace = True)
```

I tried writing a for loop but it was not working

Comment: What's not working? What error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete strings in a list `non_dogs` from a dataframe `clean_images`, you can use a for loop and the `drop` method of a dataframe. The code would look like this:

```
for breed in non_dogs:
    clean_breeds = clean_images[(clean_images['dog_breed'] == breed)].index
    clean_images.drop(clean_breeds, inplace=True)
```

This code will loop through each string in the `non_dogs` list. For each iteration, it will find all the rows in the dataframe `clean_images` where the value in the `dog_breed` column is equal to the current string. The indices of those rows will be stored in the variable `clean_breeds`. Then, those rows will be dropped from the dataframe using the `drop` method. The `inplace=True` argument makes sure that the changes are made to the dataframe itself, rather than creating a new dataframe with the changes.

Here's an example to help illustrate the code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a sample dataframe
clean_images = pd.DataFrame({'dog_breed': ['tiger_shark', 'labrador', 'walking_stick', 'beagle', 'water_bottle']})

# Create a list of strings to delete from the dataframe
non_dogs = ['tiger_shark', 'walking_stick', 'water_bottle']

# Use a for loop to delete the strings in the list from the dataframe
for breed in non_dogs:
    clean_breeds = clean_images[(clean_images['dog_breed'] == breed)].index
    clean_images.drop(clean_breeds, inplace=True)

# The resulting dataframe only contains rows with dog breeds
print(clean_images)
```

The output of this code will be:

```
  dog_breed
1  labrador
3    beagle
```